# RecyclerView adapter not set

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have set the Adapter in `RecyclerView` and my list size is Dynamically(2) that I send in adapter.
But when I debugged my code, `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` never called.

This is my code where I set the adapter.

```
mRecycler_Downloaded_List.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true));
mRecycler_Downloaded_List.setHasFixedSize(true);
PurchaseListAdapterDownloded = new Recycler_purchase_list_adapter_downloaded(PurchaseList_Dummy.this, mList_downlaoded, false);
mRecycler_Downloaded_List.setAdapter(PurchaseListAdapterDownloded);
```

This is my adapter code where I get and set the value.

```
package com.structure.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.structure.R;
import com.structure.beans.Response_GetVideoDetail;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by root on 26/4/17.
 */
public class Recycler_purchase_list_adapter_downloaded extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Recycler_purchase_list_adapter_downloaded.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    Typeface face;
    ArrayList<Response_GetVideoDetail.ResponseBean.VideodetailsBean> mList;
    View view;
    boolean mIsDownloadedList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;



    public Recycler_purchase_list_adapter_downloaded(Context context, ArrayList<Response_GetVideoDetail.ResponseBean.VideodetailsBean> mList, boolean mIsDownloadedList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mList = mList;
        this. inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mIsDownloadedList = mIsDownloadedList;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // View view  = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_purchase_list, parent, false);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_purchase_list, parent, false);
        System.out.println("OnCreateView"+"onCreateViewHolder>>>>>>>>>>>>");
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.mtvName.setText(mList.get(position).getName());
        holder.mDesc.setText(mList.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.itemTime_tv.setText(mList.get(position).getDuration());
        Glide.with(context).load(/*APIs.IMGAE_BASE_URL +*/ mList.get(position).getPic())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .dontTransform().dontAnimate()
                .error(R.drawable.demo_song).into(holder.mImg);

        System.out.println("OnCreateView"+"onBindViewHolder>>>>>>>>>>>>");



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mList.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mtvName, itemTime_tv,mDesc;
        private ContentLoadingProgressBar mProgressBar;
        private RelativeLayout mLayout;
        // private ItemPurchaseListBinding binding;
        private ImageView mImg;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mtvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_item);
            mDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            itemTime_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemtime);
            mProgressBar = (ContentLoadingProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            mImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_songName);
            mLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rel_purchaselist);

            // itemTime_tv.setTypeface(face);
            //  mtvName.setTypeface(face);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //  getAdapterPosition();
                    //     registration.getImage(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }

    }




}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I have searched everything.
If someone has a solution then please share. I have debugged the code when I set the adapter the list size is 1.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share code of initialisation of mList_downlaoded and also updation

Comment: show your complete activity

Comment: ArrayList<Response_GetVideoDetail.ResponseBean.VideodetailsBean> mList_downlaoded=new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Show your activity code also.

Comment: Are you sure this value `mList_downlaoded` is not empty?

Comment: absolutely sure

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier for you to manipulate your adapter if you separate the creation of your adapter and the setter of your list.

You can start with the initialisation :

```
mRecycler_Downloaded_List.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true));
mRecycler_Downloaded_List.setHasFixedSize(true);
PurchaseListAdapterDownloded = new Recycler_purchase_list_adapter_downloaded(PurchaseList_Dummy.this,false);
mRecycler_Downloaded_List.setAdapter(PurchaseListAdapterDownloded);
```

And then, when it is already created you add the list with a method setList:

```
private void setList(ArrayList<Response_GetVideoDetail.ResponseBean.VideodetailsBean> mList) {
       this.mList = mList;
       notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: i put the inside adpter.where i call the set list method.

Comment: you should put the method setList in the adapter class. And call the method in your activity. 
That way you can be sure your adapter is completely created before calling the notifyOnDataSetChanged

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting adapter before adding data in your mList_downlaoded list. So If you are initializing adapter before adding data in list then just call 
PurchaseListAdapterDownloded.notifyDataSetChanged(); after adding data to list.